# local.ERROR: Call to a member function users() on null in /app/Listeners/NewUserRegistered/CreateBoatUserRole.php:35

Tags: laravel

Sorry for my bad english, swedish is my main language.

Im trying to figure out the error. but this is to mutch for me to figure out.

Im new with laravel, but im trying to figure out whats the problem is.

```
[2020-03-11 19:30:31] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function users() on null in /var/www/html/app/Listeners/NewUserRegistered/CreateBoatUserRole.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Listeners\NewUserRegistered\CreateBoatUserRole->handle(Object(App\Events\NewUserRegistered))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(347): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}(Object(App\Events\NewUserRegistered))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(221): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(217): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('App\\Events\\NewU...')
#5 /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/User/RegistrationController.php(63): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('fire', Array)
#6 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\User\RegistrationController->postRegister(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('postRegister', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\User\RegistrationController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'postRegister')
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /var/www/html/app/Http/Middleware/SentinelRedirectIfAuthenticated.php(42): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\SentinelRedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\User\RegistrationController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'postRegister')
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'postRegister')
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#34 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#44 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#49 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#61 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#62 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#63 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#64 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#65 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#67 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#68 /var/www/html/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 /var/www/html/server.php(21): require_once('/var/www/html/p...')
#70 {main}
```

this is the new user CreateBoatUserRole

```
public function handle(NewUserRegistered $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;

        // Assign the user role to the users
        $userRole = Sentinel::findRoleBySlug('user');
        $userRole->users()->attach($user);

        //insert into profile table
        $boat_user = new \App\BoatUserProfile;
        $boat_user->user_id = $user->id;
        $boat_user->save();
    }
```

I have search everywhere but i cant find the right answer, so now i hope you can help me.

UPPDATE : 
i manage to fix the problem my self, But something is strange, when i registrate a user i recive a activation mail, i activate.

But when i try to login it says ** Sorry! Incorrect Username and/or Password.**

Can it be that it doesent add api_token to the db.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't handling a case for nulls:

```
// Assign the user role to the users
$userRole = Sentinel::findRoleBySlug('user');

if (null === $userRole) {
    // do something here so the code
    // after the block doesn't fail
    abort(404, "Unable to find a role by slug"); // <-- example
}
```

Your problem may also stem further up. Perhaps you need to do some discovery as to why `Sentinel::findRoleBySlug('user')` returns `null`.